# Displaying Muticolumn Headers and Data In Two Columns

Tags: php

I need to select multi-column information from a table and display it in another table which has just two columns. The scenario is this:
First Table(multi-columns):

```
      MATH111  MATH112  MATH113 MATH114
      67          89      54      23
```

I  want to  display it in this(two column table):

```
       Course      Score
       MATH111      67
       MATH112      89
       MATH113      54
       MATH114      23
```

I am conversant enough in php to obtain and display the information from the multicolumn table:

```
     "select * from xx where id=''";
      echo "<table border='1'>
   <tr>
<th>MATH111</th>
  <th>MATH112</th>
 <th>MATH113</th>
<th>MATH114</th>
  </tr>";
while($row=(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['MATH111'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['MATH112'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['MATH113'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['MATH114'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
 }    
   echo "</table>";
```

The table i want to display it in will be :

```
       echo '<table><tr><th>Course</th><th>Score</th></tr>';
```

What i need is help on code to display it as i have outlined above, which is in this format:

```
         Course      Score
       MATH111      67
       MATH112      89
       MATH113      54
       MATH114      23
```

Please let me add that the values for the "course" column
is based on the table being selected.So i can not hard code it.

Answer (score 0):

re-write your SQL query to something like this

```
select 'MATH111' Course, MATH111 Score from xx where id=something
union
select 'MATH112' Course, MATH112 Score from xx where id=something
union
select 'MATH113' Course, MATH113 Score from xx where id=something
union
select 'MATH114' Course, MATH114 Score from xx where id=something
```

and that should take care of the rest

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
echo '<tr><td>MATH111</td><td>', $row['MATH111'], '</td></tr>',
     '<tr><td>MATH112</td><td>', $row['MATH112'], '</td></tr>' [ ... ];
```